# fatal : The requested URL returned error: 403 permission denied

Tags: git

I have my GitHub account in my laptop. But few day ago my friend access his GitHub from my laptop and did changes in `user.name` and `user.email`. After that I changed to my credentials. Still it showing following fatal.

```
$ git push origin master
remote: Permission to Jayshree2816/test.git denied to mubu4111.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Jayshree2816/test.git/': The requested
URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: Maybe ask your friend? Undo those changes.

Comment: We can delete GitHub password from System. Here the path to change the password : Windows> Credential manager > Windows Credentials > Generic Credentials.. It works